# npm run build in docker container never exits

Tags: docker, npm

I tried to move angular building in docker container. It successfully generates dist folder and files in it, but npm script stays running infinitely. Interesting thing is that on the host it stops using node 1.18 but has same behavior using node 1.19. I changed my docker node version to 1.18 and nothing changed.

Dockerfile contains this:

```
FROM node:18.12 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```